# How to form JSON from this multidimensional array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

My query returns the following:

```
post_id    post_type    post_text
1          text         bla1
2          pic          bla2
3          text         bla3
```

I loop through this result as follows:

```
$posts = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $post = array();
    $post['post_id']         = $row->post_id;
    $post['post_type']       = $row->post_type;
    $post['post_text']       = $row->post_text;
    $posts[] = $post;
}
$data['posts'] = $posts;

return $data;
```

If I `json_encode` and output from my controller I get this:

```
{
    "stream": {
        "posts": [{
            "post_id": "1",
            "post_type": "text",
            "post_text": "bla1",
        },
        {
            "post_id": "2",
            "post_type": "pic",
            "post_text": "bla2",
        },
        {
            "post_id": "3",
            "post_type": "text",
            "post_text": "bla3",            
        }]
    }
}
```

However if a post has comments, my query returns

```
post_id    post_type    post_text    comment_id    comment_text
1          text         bla1         7             asd
1          text         bla1         8             sdf
2          pic          bla2
3          text         bla3         10            rty
3          text         bla3         11            yuo
```

How should I set up the foreach loop to build an array that will output JSON like this?

```
{
    "stream": {
        "posts": [{
            "post_id": "1",
            "post_type": "text",
            "post_text": "bla1",
            "comment": [{
                "comment_id": "7",
                "comment_text": "asd",
            },
            {
                "comment_id": "8",
                "comment_text": "sdf",
            }],
        },
        {
            "post_id": "2",
            "post_type": "pic",
            "post_text": "bla2",
        },
        {
            "post_id": "3",
            "post_type": "text",
            "post_text": "bla3",            
            "comment": [{
                "comment_id": "10",
                "comment_text": "rty",
            },
            {
                "comment_id": "11",
                "comment_text": "yuo",
            }],
        }]
    }
}
```

This JSON is consumed on Secha framework as follows:

```
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'jsonp',
                        url: 'http://myurl',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            rootProperty: 'stream.posts'
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This can be done with a little modification to your result set loop, but I think you should be concerned with how your managing your data. Are you holding entire post information for each *comment* on the post?

Comment: yes but open to sugestions on changing my query - since it uses a left join, duplicate rows are returned if there's >1 comment

Comment: Ahh ok, personally I prefer to query each post individually for the existence of comments inside the result set loop. I realize there may be people pushing for querying as little as possible, but this solution is more straightforward and "normalized". Plus, if you are limiting your *post* query then its not that bad. Also, doing it this way will make your construction of the array a little easier.

Comment: To construct the array in the method your using now, a tip I could give would be to make the key for each *post* array the *id* of the post. That way you can easily refer to it (if it exists) and add a comment.

Comment: yeah I use that construct for sending the array to a view, but now I need to build the array as above for JSON to send it to mobile framework (Sencha) -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I prefer to query each post individually for the existence of comments, here would be one attempt to construct the array using one query.

```
$posts=array();
$data = array();
foreach($query->result() as $row){
  // if the post hasn't been created in the array
  // create it
  if(!isset($posts[$row['post_id']])){
    $posts[$row['post_id']] = array(
      "post_type" => $row['post_type'],
      "post_text" => $row['post_text']
    );
  }
  // if a comment is found
  if(isset($row['comment_id'])){
    $posts[$row['post_id']]['comments'][] = array(
      "comment_id" => $row['comment_id'];
      "comment_text" => $row['comment_text'];
    );
  }

}
$data['posts'] = $posts;
```

JSON encoding this array would create something like...

```
{ "posts" :
   {
     1 : {
       "post_type" : "something",
       "post_text" : "something else"
     },
     2 : {
       "post_type" : "something",
       "post_text" : "something else",
       "comments" : [
         {"comment_id":1,"comment_text":"something"},
         {"comment_id":2,"comment_text":"something"}
       ]
     },
    ....
   }
 }
```

I cant vouch for this code completely working as I haven't tested it, but it should be a start. Again, if I were you I'd just query each post individually.

Comment: thx andbeyond - the issue I may have with this solution is that the key for each post changes - and it should be the same (as my example in OP) due to the way the JSON is consumed in the app

Comment: have you tried it out? the key for each post will be the ID of the post and it should not change, it only creates the *post* data once, and then on subsequent loops it will only add *comment* data (if it exists)

Comment: I meant the key will change from post to post (1, 2...) which prevents me from accessing all posts as an array with the same key

Comment: I still don't understand the issue. This should actually be more dynamic for you, because you can loop through the post set using foreach() OR grab a specific post if you have the ID using $posts[$post_id].

Comment: I added the code in OP used on my JS framework to read the JSON - there you see that the `rootProperty` will target  the JSON array `posts` allowing to pick fields within `posts` such as `post_text` etc. If there is a **variable** key instead of `posts` then I cannot target `post_text` anymore, since the JSON reader would have to change for each iteration eg: `stream.posts.1`, `stream.posts.2`, etc -- in essence all posts need to be in the same array

Comment: How are you iterating? You can use for-in syntax, as, `for(var post_id in stream.posts)` to iterate the array instead of a conventional for loop.

Comment: thx for the direction -- I posted an answer with the code that finally worked - it takes some wrangling but I got what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP syntax so I wont write the code. However this is not a PHP problem, but an algorithm problem.

What you could do to handle this data is doing it in three steps, with a intermediate result that would be a dictionary of posts. In this dictionary, keys will be post ids, and values will be posts.

1/ Iterate over the lines returned by your query. For each of this lines, check if the post involved in this line exists in the dictionary. No -> Add a new post object. Yes -> Just add the comment to the existing post object.

2/ Iterate through your dictionary to add each post contained in it to an array.

3/ Sort your array by the id of the post (here i'm assuming that the id is in the same order as the posts, but just a little advice: you should probably have a post date and sort by post date).

If you master PHP syntax, your should be able to implement it easily. Don't hesitate to submit an edit if you know the PHP syntax for this.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
      // if the post hasn't been created in the array
      // create it
        if(!isset($post[$row->post_id])){
            $post[$row->post_id] = array(
              "post_id" => $row->post_id,
              "post_text" => $row->post_text
            );
        }
        // if a comment is found
        if(isset($row->comment_id)){
            $post[$row->post_id]['comments'][] = array(
              "comment_id" => $row->comment_id,
              "comment_text" => $row->comment_text
            );
        }
    }

    return $posts[] = array_values($post);
```

returns this (what I need):

```
   [
     {
       "post_id"   : "something",
       "post_text" : "something else"
     },
     {
       "post_id"   : "something",
       "post_text" : "something else",
       "comments" : [
         {"comment_id":1,"comment_text":"something"},
         {"comment_id":2,"comment_text":"something"}
       ]
     },
    ....
   ]
```